# Случайное перемещение точки в пространстве matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Пишу в jupyter notebook. Координаты создаются. Но нет ни точки, ни ее движения. В чем может быть проблема?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

%matplotlib notebook


def random_unit_vector():
    angle = np.random.random() * 2 * np.pi
    return np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle) + np.sin(angle)


def get_random_walk(num_steps):
    locations = np.zeros((3, num_steps))
    for i in range(1, num_steps):
        next_x, next_y, next_z = random_unit_vector()
        locations[0, i] = locations[0, i-1] + next_x
        locations[1, i] = locations[1, i-1] + next_y
        locations[2, i] = locations[2, i-1] + next_z
    return locations


def random_step(num_steps, max_step=0.05):
    start_pos = np.random.random(3)
    steps = np.random.uniform(-max_step, max_step, size=(num_steps, 3))
    return start_pos + np.cumsum(steps, axis=0)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection="3d", xlim=(-10, 10), ylim=(-10, 10), zlim=(-10, 10))

step, = plt.plot([], [], [])

num_steps = 50
all_steps = get_random_walk(num_steps)
all_steps = random_step(num_steps)


def update(step_num: int):
    loc = all_steps[..., step_num]
    step.set_data(loc)
    step.set_3d_properties(loc)
    return step


anim = FuncAnimation(
    fig,
    update,
    num_steps,
    interval=500,
)

plt.show;
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy не, это не помогло

Answer (score 0):

`update` перепишите так:

```
def update(step_num: int):
    loc = all_steps[:step_num, ...]
    step.set_data(loc[..., :2].T)
    step.set_3d_properties(loc[..., 2])
    return step
```

Последнюю строку так:

```
plt.show()
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое!